# windows10でgem install rubocopがインストールできない

Tags: ruby, rubygems

atomを使ってruby on railsの開発をしています。
atomのpackageの`linter-rubocop`を導入するために、
rubocopのgemをインストールしたいのですが、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいインストールできません。

どのようにすればインストールできそうでしょうか？
どなたかご教授いただければと思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
$ gem install rubocop
ERROR:  Error installing rubocop:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.3/ext/jaro_winkler
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0 -r ./siteconf20190704-17528-1bw0161.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.3/ext/jaro_winkler
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.3/ext/jaro_winkler
make "DESTDIR="
make failedNo such file or directory - make "DESTDIR="

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/jaro_winkler-1.5.3/gem_make.out
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
```

Comment: Rubyは何をどうやってインストールしましたか？

Answer (score 1):

ネイティブエクステンションの生成に失敗しているように見えます。どのrubyを設定されたか不明ですが、rubyinstall2 を使ってインストールされたのであれば、正しくmsysが設定されてないのではないでしょうか？インストールについては以下が参考になると思います。

- RubyInstaller2でWindows環境にRuby 2.4 + Rails 5.0.2をインストールする
  https://qiita.com/jnchito/items/08b5be458134073c60e3

atom については以下が参考になるかもしれません。

- Windows7のAtomでrubocopを使えるようになるまで
  https://qiita.com/hrix/items/8ed6e14c657d4bcf2d04